# AWS S3 API list-multipart-uploads what is the timezone of the timestamp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, timezone, aws-cli

I am viewing multipart uploads using `AWS CLI v2` like so:

```bsh
aws s3api list-multipart-uploads --bucket my-bucket-name
```

The `Uploads` key of the response has an `Initiated` key.  From the [`list-multipart-uploads` docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-multipart-uploads.html):

> Date and time at which the multipart upload was initiated.

For me (I'm located in the [Pacific Time Zone (PT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone)), it looks like this:

```
"Initiated": "2020-06-02T02:20:49+00:00"
```

What is the timezone of this timestamp?

---

**Background**

I am located in the [Pacific Time Zone (PT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone).

The region the upload was initiated from and where I ran the `list-multipart-uploads` command is `us-west-2` (see [Regions, Availability Zones, and Local Zones](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html)).

To me, it looks like the beginning format is: `yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` (based on [these](https://help.sumologic.com/03Send-Data/Sources/04Reference-Information-for-Sources/Timestamps%2C-Time-Zones%2C-Time-Ranges%2C-and-Date-Formats))

Is this timestamp supposed to be pre-converted to pacific time, or is it given in UTC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be an [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) format timestamp.

If it ends in `+hh:mm`, which your example does, then that indicates that it is `hh` hours and `mm` minutes ahead of UTC. In your case of `+00:00`, it *is* UTC.

If it ends in `Z` e.g. `2020-06-02T02:20:49Z` then it is UTC.